# Trigger Circuit

Tags: voltage, digital-logic, circuit-design

Whenever voltage goes above 19V , it should provide High signal (2.5V to 5V) to the G pin and rest of the time it provide Low signal (below 0.5V). The currently shown resistor divider solution will not work.

[image: schematic diagram]

Comment: Please don't post [duplicate questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/495055/trigger-small-circuit-based-on-input-voltage).  To add information to an existing question use the `edit` link below the text of your question.

Comment: First of all, this is a duplicate post, and second of all, is there a question in this post? What is the question? If you can't put enough effort in your own question that you need answered, why do you expect us to put any effort in answering it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger small circuit based on input voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/495055/trigger-small-circuit-based-on-input-voltage)

Comment: @SamGibson: Your link doesn't work.

Comment: @EdinFifić - Hi, At the time it was posted (2 hours before your comment) "my" link *was* valid! In fact it linked to a question where you yourself had added a comment, asking the OP to update *that original question* with the schematic from here. Instead, between the time of "my" comment (which is actually auto-generated by the system, when someone flags a question as a duplicate) and the time of your comment, the OP *deleted* their original posting - instead of updating it as you & I requested. As a >10k user, I can still see the deleted question via "my" link. I hope that explains things!

Comment: OK, I see. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: Comparator powered from 5V. Divide Vin to be within 5V supply range. Set reference to comparator. Drive G pin with comparator. In this case the 5V supply with a resistor divider should be accurate enough as a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an analog comparator to be able to set a precise switching threshold.